# If statment on button content . WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

i have listview one button( default content == "Add") and 1 textbox. On list view double click event buttons.Content=="Edit" and text box fills with information from listview.

this if statment does not work correctly

```
            if (btnAddFloor.Content == "Add")
            {
                HProDataContext db = new HProDataContext();
                floor f = new floor { floorname = txtFloorName.Text };
                db.floors.InsertOnSubmit(f);
                db.SubmitChanges();
                RefreshListViewFloor();
            }
            else
            {
                int currentID = Convert.ToInt32(listViewFloors.SelectedValue);

                HProDataContext db = new HProDataContext();
                floor f = db.floors.Single(p => p.id == currentID);
                f.floorname = txtFloorName.Text;
                db.SubmitChanges();
                RefreshListViewFloor();
                txtFloorName.Text = null;
                RefreshListViewRoom();
            }
```

and on btnAddFloor.Content == "Add" is green underline
can anyone help me?

XAML

```
    <GroupBox Header="Floors" Height="287" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,32,0,0" Name="GroupBoxFloors" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="342">
        <Grid>
            <Button Content="Add" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="169,37,0,0" Name="btnAddFloor" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnAddFloor_Click" />
            <ListView Height="192" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,66,0,0" Name="listViewFloors" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="318" ItemsSource="{Binding FloorCollection}" SelectedValuePath="ID" MouseDoubleClick="listViewFloors_MouseDoubleClick">
                <ListView.View >
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="60" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="FloorName" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FloorName}"/>

                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,37,0,0" Name="txtFloorName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="157" TextChanged="txtFloorName_TextChanged" />
            <Button Content="Remove" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="249,37,0,0" Name="btnRemoveFloor" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnRemoveFloor_Click" />
            <Label Content="Floor Name" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
```

Comment: thanks for replay i posted xaml

Comment: What means "does not work correctly"? Are you getting a compile error? Exception? something else?

Comment: This is because Button.Content is not of type String, but Object

Comment: does not work correctly its means that if cottent is add it may go to the else statment where content must be edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Button.Content is of type Object, using the "==" operator will compare pointers.
What you want to do is:

btnAddFloor.Content.ToString() == "Add"

Comment: Better still, use the static function `string.Equals(string, string, StringComparisonType)`.